# Follow Request Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented a Follower/Following Relationship,i want to extend the functionality ,i.e. in my current implementation User 'A' follows User 'B' without the acknowledgement of User 'B'.I want User 'A' to send a request to User 'B' and then User 'B' either accepts or rejects it.I want it to be like the Instagram model not Facebook model.[User A sends follow request to User B.If User B accepts request then User A follows User B and User B is not following User A,to do so User B has to send a request to User A].

My files:

schema.rb

```
class CreateFollowJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def change
    create_table 'follows' do |t|
      t.integer 'following_id', :null => false
      t.integer 'follower_id', :null => false
      t.boolean :accepted, default: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :follows, :following_id
    add_index :follows, :follower_id
    add_index :follows, [:following_id, :follower_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

app/models/follow.rb

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :follower, foreign_key: 'follower_id', class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :following, foreign_key: 'following_id', class_name: 'User'
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
has_many :follower_relationships, foreign_key: :following_id, class_name: 'Follow'
has_many :followers, through: :follower_relationships, source: :follower

has_many :following_relationships, foreign_key: :follower_id, class_name: 'Follow'
has_many :following, through: :following_relationships, source: :following

def follow(user_id)  
    following_relationships.create(following_id: user_id)
end

def unfollow(user_id)
    following_relationships.find_by(following_id: user_id).destroy
end
```

routes.rb

```
post ':user_name/follow_user', to: 'relationships#follow_user', as: :follow_user
post ':user_name/unfollow_user', to: 'relationships#unfollow_user', as: :unfollow_user
```

app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController  
  def follow_user
    @user = User.find_by! user_name: params[:user_name]
    if current_user.follow @user.id
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def unfollow_user
    @user = User.find_by! user_name: params[:user_name]
    if current_user.unfollow @user.id
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Well in Instagram, users can be followed by any users without any requests.

Comment: you are following michael hartl's railstutorial.org right?

Comment: no @icemelt  i am not,even in michael hartl's tutorial a user can follow another without any request

Comment: yes @Pavan what you've said is correct but i'm referring to the scenario where the user being followed sets account to private,then the potential 'following' user sends a follow request

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add `status:boolean default:false` to your following_relationships class

then you need to make a controller that notify the followed user about a new follower,

then you need make another controller for the followed user to edit the status from false to be true

like

```
def accept_follower
  @relationships = current_user.following_relationships.find_by(follower_id: params[:follower_id])
  @relationships.update_attributes(active: true)
end

def ignore_follower
  current_user.following_relationships.find_by(follower_id: params[:follower_id]).destroy
end
```

then you need to fix your query about follower/following only select where status= true

```
has_many :followers, -> { where(status: true) } through: :follower_relationships, source: :follower
```

Comment: i have added t.boolean :accepted, default: false to CreateFollowJoinTable

Comment: then you need to fix your query about follower/following only select where accepted= true